# Excel dates and R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, excel

First of all I already looked for an answer to my question but all the methods and scripts in other answers are not quite working with mine. Im beginner in R so have me patience please! :(

I Have a short data frame I randomnly created to have a practice before it gets to Big Data frames. I made it with the same Variables as the original should be but way shorter.

[image: Date plot]

The problem im having is that Excel takes dates with month first, so R is confused and its putting 10/1/2015 first. When is supossed to be last. What can i do so R order correctly the dates?

Also I want to for example calculate the Total ammount of money (Data$Total) That i made in one month. What would be the script for that?

Also if im already here i could kill two birds with one stone. I know there is already a answer for this, but the answer i saw involves using Direct.labels package that completely messes up with the whole graphic. What would you advise for the labels not to go over the plot margin? Thanks.

[missing Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2ctC.jpg)

```
Dput()
 dput(Data)
structure(list(JOB = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("JAGER", 
"PLAY", "RUGBY"), class = "factor"), AGENCY = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("LONDON", "WILHEL"), class = "factor"), 
    DATE = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("10/1/2015", 
    "10/3/2015", "10/9/2015", "9/24/2015", "9/26/2015"), class = "factor"), 
    RATE = c(90L, 90L, 100L, 90L, 90L), HS = c(8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
    4L), TOTAL = c(720L, 540L, 400L, 540L, 360L)), .Names = c("JOB", 
"AGENCY", "DATE", "RATE", "HS", "TOTAL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
>
```

Thanks for everything.

Comment: 1) these questions belong on stackoverflow, not crossvalidated. 2) ask one question per post, not a hodgepodge of unrelated hangups.

Comment: @AdamO Sorry about that mate. Im new to all of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dates you generated are stored in a CSV file as strings, and when you sort strings you get what you see. You need to tell R that these are dates, and you need to tell R what format the dates are in.

Look at R's `as.Date` function to convert your string into a date. The default is probably correct, but if you need to specify the date format, you can look at the `strptime` function.

You'd do something like

`Data$theDate <- as.Date (Data$theDate)`

or

`Data$theDate <- as.Date (Data$theDate, "%m/%d/%Y")`

if that is the appropriate date format for your data.

Comment: +1 As usual, an important caveat is to make sure the date, whilst appearing in every way and function like a character object, is actually character coded. All my R scripts begin with `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, otherwise, OP will need to convert CSV read dates from factor into character for your code to work.

Comment: +1 for the comment. In this case, things will work because the factors are turned back into strings. But in a case where numbers are required `as.numeric (aFactor)` is not what you want -- rather `as.numeric (as.character (aFactor))` is.

Comment: Thanks guys! That worked wonders. My only question is how would i visualize the sum() of the TOTAL I made in one month. Can I set a sum(TOTAL) from 1/1/2015 to 1/2/2015 (1st of january till 2nd)

Comment: @Wayne That's hysterical. R finally did the obvious thing `getS3method('as.Date', 'factor')` casts it to character before casting it to factor. Used to use the numeric coding of the factor level. SMH

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided example code for your graphic, but for most drawing graphics (lines, segments, legends, pch, etc.), using `, xpd=TRUE` allows you to extrapolate beyond the inner margins of a plot. Printing over the box generally looks ugly. The only guaranteed solution is to set better plotting regions using `, xlim=` and `, ylim=`.